# Why won't Mathematica simplify tensor products fully?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, tensors

I am working on a project and part of the output of my code is the following:
$$
\text{a1}\otimes\text{a2}+\text{a1}\otimes(\text{a1}\otimes\text{a1}-\text{a2})-\text{a1}\otimes\text{a1}\otimes\text{a1}.
$$

To me this clearly simplifies to 0, but for some reason, Mathematica cannot see this even if I use `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`. Is there any way to help it to see this?

```
In[283]:= ExpandAll[ a1\[TensorProduct]a2 + a1\[TensorProduct](-a2 + a1\[TensorProduct]a1) 
 - a1\[TensorProduct]a1\[TensorProduct]a1]

Out[283]= a1\[TensorProduct]a2 + a1\[TensorProduct](-a2 + a1\[TensorProduct]a1)
- a1\[TensorProduct]a1\[TensorProduct]a1
```

Comment: Here it's considered helpful to show your own efforts and share your code in a **[well formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) instead of images** or links to external files, so we can quickly **Copy&Paste** your code, test it, and  see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question accordingly. This [question in Meta](https://wolfr.am/v57TjMS9) could be useful.

Comment: @rhermans I didn't put the raw code as it was very ugly and didn't show my point as well as an image. I have replaced with the code now.

Comment: Still it's better that you share your *ugly code* than to ask us to guess and type the code for you. Using images it's fine provided you also provide plain text code (in `InputForm`) that we can Copy&Paste. Thanks for editing your question. Don't forget to take the [tour]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
expr = a1\[TensorProduct]a2 +  a1\[TensorProduct](-a2 + a1\[TensorProduct]a1) - 
   a1\[TensorProduct]a1\[TensorProduct]a1
```

[image]

```
TensorExpand @ expr
```

> 0

Comment: while your solution works its a bit disappointing that FullSimplify does not attempt TensorExpand?

Comment: @chris, I agree. `PowerExpand` and `ComplexExpand` are also not used by `FullSimplify` because  they _"make special assumptions on input"_. Perhaps `TensorExpand` is not used for the same reason.

Comment: @chris you can always manually add `TensorExpand` to `TransformationFunctions`: `FullSimplify[expr, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, TensorExpand}]`.